QGIS crashing on Linux when trying to browse folders
QGIS 3.83.3 Grenoble working on endeavouros,
Any time I click a button that requires browsing the file system QGIS crashes.
If I try to export a map, it crashes when trying to load the window that browses for folders. Same happens if I click Save As for the project itself or if I click to browse for a folder when exporting a layer. The project loads, saves and works fine but QGIS dies specifically when trying to display the folders when browsing for a location or folder.
I have no external plugins installed.
Deleting the QGIS app data folder in '/home/user/.local/share/QGIS' briefly solves the problem but then the issue randomly starts back up again after a few hours of use. I have attempted upgrading and downgrading QGIS and this did not change the behaviour. Problem started about a month ago and did not coincide with an update.

Can you use another computer and ensure that it is not a hardware problem?

Question, a hardware problem as compared to what? do you mean send my qgis project over to another computer and see if the problem repeats itself? Unfortunately its the only Linux pc in the house and also this is a large QGIS project with hundreds of associated files troughout my computer system. I have several qgis projects for work on my PC and some of them will give me the issue and some wont, but this will also fluctuate over time, almost as if they will "go bad" after some unknown event. As mentioned, the problem goes away temporarily when resetting QGIS from scratch.

I have a similar problem on Debian. Sometime QGIS hangs when browsing the file system, other times (more often) it is Spyder. I've assumed something is broken in my hardware or linux so I'm going to reinstall everything...
